# ObjectMapper Exception , while reading the message from the SQS Queue

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a Spring Boot Application which publish the message to AWS SNS Topic

```
@GetMapping("/sendInvoice")
    public String publishMessageToSNSTopic() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Employee e1 = new Employee("raghu", 305652, 2000f);
        String employeeJsonPayload = gson.toJson(e1);

        MessageHeaders messageHeaders = new MessageHeaders(Map.of("source","aos"));
        MessageHeaderPayload messageHeaderPayload = new MessageHeaderPayload(messageHeaders, employeeJsonPayload);

        String base64String = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(SerializationUtils.serialize(messageHeaderPayload));
        System.out.println("base1 64 String := " + base64String);

        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest(snsConfig.getTopicarn(), base64String);
        amazonSNSClient.publish(publishRequest);

        return "notification-new send successfully " + messageHeaderPayload.getTransportHeader().get("id");
    }
```

MessageHeaderPayload.java

```
public class MessageHeaderPayload implements  java.io.Serializable {

    private MessageHeaders transportHeader;
    private String payload;

    public MessageHeaderPayload(MessageHeaders transportHeader,
                                String payload) {
        this.transportHeader = transportHeader;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public void setTransportHeader(MessageHeaders transportHeader) {
        this.transportHeader = transportHeader;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public MessageHeaders getTransportHeader() {
        return transportHeader;
    }

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

This is getting published to the SNS and which send a copy to the SQS..

```
base1 64 String :=
rO0ABXNyADBjb20uZXhhbXBsZS5hd3NzbnNwdWJsaXNoZXIuTWVzc2FnZUhlYWRlclBheWxvYWQkZXDoSrr1uQIAAkwAB3BheWxvYWR0ABJMamF2YS9sYW5nL1N0cmluZztMAA90cmFuc3BvcnRIZWFkZXJ0AC5Mb3JnL3NwcmluZ2ZyYW1ld29yay9tZXNzYWdpbmcvTWVzc2FnZUhlYWRlcnM7eHB0AGZ7Im5hbWUiOiJyYWdodSIsImlkIjozMDU2NTIsImludm9pY2VBbW91bnQiOjIwMDAuMCwicmVxdWVzdElkIjoiMTliMDMxZTktMDkzYi00YWFhLWFmMDUtNjc4MDcyMjBkNzJmIn1zcgAsb3JnLnNwcmluZ2ZyYW1ld29yay5tZXNzYWdpbmcuTWVzc2FnZUhlYWRlcnNhoZX3wWNd2AMAAUwAB2hlYWRlcnN0AA9MamF2YS91dGlsL01hcDt4cHNyABFqYXZhLnV0aWwuSGFzaE1hcAUH2sHDFmDRAwACRgAKbG9hZEZhY3RvckkACXRocmVzaG9sZHhwP0AAAAAAAAN3CAAAAAQAAAADdAAGc291cmNldAADYW9zdAACaWRzcgAOamF2YS51dGlsLlVVSUS8mQP3mG2FLwIAAkoADGxlYXN0U2lnQml0c0oAC21vc3RTaWdCaXRzeHA13D/tMEMyuiMbKeEPhIzZdAAJdGltZXN0YW1wc3IADmphdmEubGFuZy5Mb25nO4vkkMyPI98CAAFKAAV2YWx1ZXhyABBqYXZhLmxhbmcuTnVtYmVyhqyVHQuU4IsCAAB4cAAAAYqPFTNqeHg=
```

I have no question on the above code, which publishes to the SNS Queue

SNS Topic pushes the message to the SQS Queue

I have Lambda function as which listens to the SQS Queue

```
@Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        for(SQSEvent.SQSMessage msg : event.getRecords()){
            String messageBody =  msg.getBody();

            System.out.println("messageBOdy4 is := " + messageBody);
            Message message = null;
            try {
                new JSONObject(messageBody);
                logger.log("valid json := " + messageBody);
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                // edited, to include @Arthur's comment
                // e.g. in case JSONArray is valid as well...
                logger.log("json error := "+ ex);
            }
            try {
                 message = JSONMAPPER.readValue(messageBody,Message.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            logger.log("My Latest messageID4  is := " + msg.getMessageId());
            logger.log("md5body " + msg.getMd5OfBody());
            logger.log("message is := " + message.getMessage());
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.getMessage());
            Employee e2 = (Employee) SerializationUtils.deserialize(decodedString);
            logger.log("actual message " + decodedString);
            logger.log("Employee e2 := " + e2);
            logger.log("attributes := " + msg.getAttributes());
            logger.log("message attribute := " + msg.getMessageAttributes());
            logger.log("full message := " + msg.getBody());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Message Class:

```
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import java.sql.Timestamp;


public class Message {

    @JsonIgnore
    private String type;

    private String messageId;

    private String topicArn;

    private String message;

    private Timestamp timeStamp;

    private String signatureVersion;

    private String signature;

    private String signingCertURL;

    private String unsubscribeURL;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String Type, String messageId, String topicArn, String Message, Timestamp timeStamp, String signatureVersion, String signature, String signingCertURL, String unsubscribeURL) {
        this.type = Type;
        this.messageId = messageId;
        this.topicArn = topicArn;
        this.message = Message;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.signatureVersion = signatureVersion;
        this.signature = signature;
        this.signingCertURL = signingCertURL;
        this.unsubscribeURL = unsubscribeURL;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = this.type;
    }

    public String getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getTopicArn() {
        return topicArn;
    }

    public void setTopicArn(String topicArn) {
        this.topicArn = topicArn;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String Message) {
        this.message = Message;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Timestamp timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public String getSignatureVersion() {
        return signatureVersion;
    }

    public void setSignatureVersion(String signatureVersion) {
        this.signatureVersion = signatureVersion;
    }

    public String getSignature() {
        return signature;
    }

    public void setSignature(String signature) {
        this.signature = signature;
    }

    public String getSigningCertURL() {
        return signingCertURL;
    }

    public void setSigningCertURL(String signingCertURL) {
        this.signingCertURL = signingCertURL;
    }

    public String getUnsubscribeURL() {
        return unsubscribeURL;
    }

    public void setUnsubscribeURL(String unsubscribeURL) {
        this.unsubscribeURL = unsubscribeURL;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
[main] INFO org.example.LambdaUtils - Consumed normal message 
messageBOdy4 is := {
"Type" : "Notification",
"MessageId" : "dc6f15a6-77a0-5934-b72e-48dcccc13109",
"TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
"Message" : "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",
"Timestamp" : "2023-09-12T19:16:49.034Z",
"SignatureVersion" : "1",
"Signature" : "hmUiSY8TIuEnazsBkVipk+quZi56JIDIXYicPbmnMGynsajTLIo1iqoK8v/CHH7URrI/btMwtRUTCv5Zw86Rgf8mG9R2ooXVZuVhUeYXlHcDSrNICPPIkg0TQ3EMADeg9VQV2FEUhwuy4ujMRYWSc7QVGsh/1JxYJQKgK6d2alMWuLJJVeNPAK/0g36Jon7xSw0en7bbFkaIeAVVBXR/1se9zbUnwXz5hdsmDLEAoUBOw36geFyUKTvxDektaXZzDYnCPEU7cnAZSbZhm4RHBeZ/fRCakQ98zaHojRjDUCEL411TKZj/qg/ecpOhM0QHMhSN6guM1R1Qtirni9sWfg==",
"SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
"UnsubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
valid json := 
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "dc6f15a6-77a0-5934-b72e-48dcccc13109",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
    "Message": "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",
    "Timestamp": "2023-09-12T19:16:49.034Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "hmUiSY8TIuEnazsBkVipk+quZi56JIDIXYicPbmnMGynsajTLIo1iqoK8v/CHH7URrI/btMwtRUTCv5Zw86Rgf8mG9R2ooXVZuVhUeYXlHcDSrNICPPIkg0TQ3EMADeg9VQV2FEUhwuy4ujMRYWSc7QVGsh/1JxYJQKgK6d2alMWuLJJVeNPAK/0g36Jon7xSw0en7bbFkaIeAVVBXR/1se9zbUnwXz5hdsmDLEAoUBOw36geFyUKTvxDektaXZzDYnCPEU7cnAZSbZhm4RHBeZ/fRCakQ98zaHojRjDUCEL411TKZj/qg/ecpOhM0QHMhSN6guM1R1Qtirni9sWfg==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Type" (class org.example.Message), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "signatureVersion", "messageId", "timeStamp", "signingCertURL", "message", "signature", "topicArn", "unsubscribeURL"])
 at [Source: 
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "dc6f15a6-77a0-5934-b72e-48dcccc13109",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
    "Message": "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",
    "Timestamp": "2023-09-12T19:16:49.034Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "hmUiSY8TIuEnazsBkVipk+quZi56JIDIXYicPbmnMGynsajTLIo1iqoK8v/CHH7URrI/btMwtRUTCv5Zw86Rgf8mG9R2ooXVZuVhUeYXlHcDSrNICPPIkg0TQ3EMADeg9VQV2FEUhwuy4ujMRYWSc7QVGsh/1JxYJQKgK6d2alMWuLJJVeNPAK/0g36Jon7xSw0en7bbFkaIeAVVBXR/1se9zbUnwXz5hdsmDLEAoUBOw36geFyUKTvxDektaXZzDYnCPEU7cnAZSbZhm4RHBeZ/fRCakQ98zaHojRjDUCEL411TKZj/qg/ecpOhM0QHMhSN6guM1R1Qtirni9sWfg==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.example.Message["Type"]): java.lang.RuntimeException
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Type" (class org.example.Message), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "signatureVersion", "messageId", "timeStamp", "signingCertURL", "message", "signature", "topicArn", "unsubscribeURL"])
 at [Source: 
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "dc6f15a6-77a0-5934-b72e-48dcccc13109",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
    "Message": "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",
    "Timestamp": "2023-09-12T19:16:49.034Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "hmUiSY8TIuEnazsBkVipk+quZi56JIDIXYicPbmnMGynsajTLIo1iqoK8v/CHH7URrI/btMwtRUTCv5Zw86Rgf8mG9R2ooXVZuVhUeYXlHcDSrNICPPIkg0TQ3EMADeg9VQV2FEUhwuy4ujMRYWSc7QVGsh/1JxYJQKgK6d2alMWuLJJVeNPAK/0g36Jon7xSw0en7bbFkaIeAVVBXR/1se9zbUnwXz5hdsmDLEAoUBOw36geFyUKTvxDektaXZzDYnCPEU7cnAZSbZhm4RHBeZ/fRCakQ98zaHojRjDUCEL411TKZj/qg/ecpOhM0QHMhSN6guM1R1Qtirni9sWfg==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.example.Message["Type"])
    at org.example.SQSSubscriber.handleRequest(SQSSubscriber.java:38)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Type" (class org.example.Message), not marked as ignorable (8 known properties: "signatureVersion", "messageId", "timeStamp", "signingCertURL", "message", "signature", "topicArn", "unsubscribeURL"])
 at [Source: 
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "dc6f15a6-77a0-5934-b72e-48dcccc13109",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
    "Message": "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",
    "Timestamp": "2023-09-12T19:16:49.034Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "hmUiSY8TIuEnazsBkVipk+quZi56JIDIXYicPbmnMGynsajTLIo1iqoK8v/CHH7URrI/btMwtRUTCv5Zw86Rgf8mG9R2ooXVZuVhUeYXlHcDSrNICPPIkg0TQ3EMADeg9VQV2FEUhwuy4ujMRYWSc7QVGsh/1JxYJQKgK6d2alMWuLJJVeNPAK/0g36Jon7xSw0en7bbFkaIeAVVBXR/1se9zbUnwXz5hdsmDLEAoUBOw36geFyUKTvxDektaXZzDYnCPEU7cnAZSbZhm4RHBeZ/fRCakQ98zaHojRjDUCEL411TKZj/qg/ecpOhM0QHMhSN6guM1R1Qtirni9sWfg==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
; line: 2, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.example.Message["Type"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:817)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:958)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1324)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1302)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:249)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3562)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2578)
    at org.example.SQSSubscriber.handleRequest(SQSSubscriber.java:36)
    ... 3 more
```

END RequestId: b83001de-fc7f-58a1-bdd0-5ca525ff814c

1. I'm not able to deserialize the jsonString to Message.class

message is coming as null.

message is Base64encoded String after converting the java class to byte[] using Serialization.

Here is the message which I have published:
You can see the base1 64 String := printed in SpringBoot Application
It is exactly matching the message in the below Object("Message")

```
{
    "Type": "Notification",
    "MessageId": "4d534ce8-f757-50c0-ba1c-11924b4166c5",
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic",
    "Message": "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",
    "Timestamp": "2023-09-12T19:19:50.203Z",
    "SignatureVersion": "1",
    "Signature": "PmNMfL9YkIvp/kdnfVSmBHdOqMtsuT+wrgrPay/pjhBNRUwtX1zDamGUldV7hxZX8Gf8rw77vs4lQYvL3o0fEo2MugXZTtkYmBDORHEBILuR+4vpylAJvbKSAPPfdCnzYh42YfrqBxLqZh9Z598F+bm/V5enWWXP4AN9oTVAVafDeVXmK73qTILsCaO6Hndz+n6/IOMvH7I7Qp/Jnb5ujWLLujeyghQI35fINCIYGmdB2iP9YYwfA0iX/U31a7bl2zM5KXz8+ptJ7uH77ngIUGoOl4vZ1GoEcizfGIRoJHFo8705KheCbpE06YOuElTs4iIwAJcENzhhst139symYg==",
    "SigningCertURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-01d088a6f77103d0fe307c0069e40ed6.pem",
    "UnsubscribeURL": "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:261640584539:InvoicingTopic:7be6400a-5025-4078-9160-0399a6a88eb0"
}
```

2. Is there any other way to retrieve the message from the above String from String messageBody =  msg.getBody();//SQSMessage.getBody(). how to retrieve the message("Message").. ..any other way other then using json mapper

Comment: why do you annotate  "@JsonIgnore private String type;" ? That's seems to be the issue.